# Can Celery deliver task results in under 10ms?

Tags: python, performance, rabbitmq, celery, low-latency

I am trying to execute a task over celery and then block on it's result with less than 10ms overhead.

A self contained example (tasks.py):

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='librabbitmq://guest@localhost//', backend='amqp')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Test Script:

```
from timeit import timeit
from tasks import add

def f():
    add.delay(2, 2).get()

timeit(f, number=100)
```

This runs with about 40ms per request on my i5 8GB ram debian linux machine.

IMHO redis as a result backend in celery relies on polling, so isn't ideal for low latency requirements?

The solution will need to deliver under 10ms RTT overhead with about 4 machines adding  tasks about every second, and about 2 task workers actually executing the tasks.

Comment: This is going to be HIGHLY dependent on your network infrastructure between machines, regardless of the ability of your task-queue implementation.

Comment: Note that your latency will be variable even just from CPU scheduling. You may be able to get average that low eventually, but you may have some messages which far exceed that time. For example, on an embedded system we develop, we sometimes see >5 seconds of latency due to priority inversion on a kernel lock. You won't likely see that bad, but you may see more than 10 ms.

Comment: @aruisdante It just feels like if it's getting 40ms on my localbox then something is *wrong*...

Comment: @avoid3d Not necessarily. If Celery doesn't short-circuit the network stack for *localhost* and instead just essentially sends to itself, then you can still get pretty variable latency.

Comment: @aruisdante But the underlying transport (rabbitmq) get's about 400us latency for the underlying requests :/

Comment: Ho you measured this 40ms ? Is this the pure execution time of the task or includes the scheduling time ?

Comment: I was measuring the round trip time from dispatch to result. Which I have gotten under 10ms, I will answer my own question when I get a moment.

Comment: Use the "rpc" backend, not the AMQP backend.  It's useless to measure the "amqp" backend if what you really want is rpc.

Comment: I'm seeing 13ms on my machine to enqueue a tiny task, process in a worker, and get a result from a `group` with the Celery client for Python. Reminder, that includes any pre-message-passing time for creating the `group` object, adding the worker to the list, etc. Not an expert on the message server setup, but I'm pretty sure I'm using Celery and RabbitMQ in RPC mode.

Answer (score 0):

Celery can (in 2023) return results within 10ms, and no longer polls redis.

I looked into this recently as I needed a low-latency task queue. Celery could consistently complete a blocking dispatch → results round trip in under 10ms on the same machine (i3-10100), with either the redis or rmq backends:

[image]

*Source: [Python task queue latency](https://www.gpxz.io/blog/queue-latency)*

Celery is still slower than using the backends directly though. There are overheads to serialisation, worker/child management, and ACKs.

Redis in particular has some nice simple primitives for hand-rolling a basic task queue, which is the route I ended up going for my latency-sensitive application.